# Vim change colorscheme from commandline

Tags: vim, command-line, themes

I want vim/macvim to override the current theme from the commandline.

Something like:

```
vim -colorscheme=solarized
```

Is there any way to tell vim/macvim to override the current .vimrc colorscheme from the commandline?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you read `$ vim --help`?

```
$ vim -c "colorscheme desert"
```